# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING with XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I am following the http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12#comments tutorial. I opened an XAMPP server and when I opened `http://localhost/iReporter` because iReporter is the name of  the folder and the error was

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iReporter/lib.php on line 5

here is the code for lib.php:

`<?`

`//setup db connection`

`$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")`

`mysqli_select_db($link, "iReport");`

`//executes a given sql query with the params and returns an array as result function

query() {`

`global $link;`

`$debug = false;`

```
//get the sql query
$args = func_get_args();
$sql = array_shift($args);
//secure the input
for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
    $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
    $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
}

//build the final query
$sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

if ($debug) print $sql;

//execute and fetch the results
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

    $rows = array();
    if ($result!==true)
    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($rows,$d);
    }

    //return json
    return array('result'=>$rows);

} else {

    //error
    return array('error'=>'Database error');
}
```

}

`//loads up the source image, resizes it and saves with -thumb in the file name
function thumb($srcFile, $sideInPx) {`

`$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcFile);`

`$width = imagesx($image);`

`$height = imagesy($image);`

`$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($sideInPx, $sideInPx);`

`imagecopyresized($thumb,$image,0,0,0,0,$sideInPx,$sideInPx,$width,$height);`

`imagejpeg($thumb, str_replace(".jpg","-thumb.jpg",$srcFile), 85);`

`imagedestroy($thumb);`
  `imagedestroy($image);`
`}`

`?>`

What is my problem? Please Help!

**--Edit--**

now it says that there is an error with line 35 when I changed 
`$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")` to 
`$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");`!

Answer (score 1):

there is a mising ";" in the line

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")
```

and  must be

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
```